# Not able to use the web3 deploy code generated by remix

Tags: contract-deployment

I am doing a helloworld contract and trying to deploy it using console. i have copied the web3 deploy code generated by remix. i Get error

" Cannot read property 'new' of undefined", new is not a function.

The following is the code

```
var deployed = helloworldContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: compiled.contracts[':HelloWorld'].bytecode, 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

The code iam trying to follow is here
https://gist.github.com/NathanMaton/c4b435d1381f196ed4d89a7240874b9a